# Inheriting from the traits class

Tags: c++, templates, traits

What are the cons of the inheriting from the **traits** class template in my own (say, conatiner) template class? Is it conventional, legal?

Comment: Most (all?) traits classes only have a static member variable, why would you want to inherit from one?

Comment: I want this to avoid multiple lines like `typedef typename traits::value_type value_type;` in `public :` section in each of my classes.

Comment: What traits? Can you post an example.

Comment: See [here](http://www.cyberguru.ru/cpp/cpp-traits.html) `vector` class part.

Comment: A lot of trait classes from <type_traits> inherit from std::integral_constant. I see no problem with it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't read Russian. Is it that hard to post an example?

Comment: @jork but there are inherited similar. This is not my case.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes `template <typename T,
          typename traits = elem_traits<T> >
class vector {/* ... */
    public:
     typedef T                                value_type;
     typedef typename traits::arg_type        arg_type;
     typedef typename traits::reference       reference;
     typedef typename traits::const_reference const_reference;

        void push_back(arg_type);

        /* ... */
};`

Comment: @Dukales sorry, i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @jrok Traits derive from traits. But I mean in question that some workable class derives from traits class to enclose all of him `typedef`s.

Comment: See Jan's answer. You sure can do it, but i wouldn't call such base class a "trait" class anymore.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Most traits classes are just static member functions, but some contain important typedef, that you want as part of the public interface of your class.  It makes sense to inherit (publicly) from those.

Comment: @jrok The term traits has a more or less formal definition, established by the person who invented the term.  A traits class is any class which has no non-static members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only traits can inherit other traits (in the strict sense of what C++ standard library calls `*_traits`), if they should only differ in some aspects. But there are other similar classes intended for inheriting that simplify defining the members. E.g. when defining iterator, you are probably going to inherit [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) to define the appropriate tag typedefs.

Comment: So you say only traits can inherit traits, but iterators may inherit what is essentially a traits type, too? Doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @ArneMertz: The point is that that's **not** a traits type. It's similar, but it's not called trait.

Comment: I think this is wrong.  It's a standard C++ idiom to inherit (publically) from a traits class, like `std::iterator`.  (`std::iterator` is, I admit, a bit special, but the general principal applies.)

Comment: @JanHudec The definition of a traits class (from the inventor of the term, Nathan Meyrs) is a class with no non-static members: all of the members are either static functions or variables, or type definitions.  By this definition, instantiations of `std::iterator` are traits.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Ok. The standard C++ library however uses the term differently. There a traits class is a template that provides information about it's template argument. Which `std::iterator` isn't.

Comment: @JanHudec In fact, I looked up the orginal article, and the original use was closer to what you describe.  I think my definition is necessary but not sufficient; the term is perhaps not as exact as I thought.  Not that it really matters in this case: the role of `std::iterator` is quite similar to that of a traits class, and above all, it's a good example of something from which you would inherit publicly, but which doesn't really define an isA relationship in the sense of OO.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, traits classes are just a bunch of typedefs. If you want to have them *all* in your class, you can inherit from them. Since they usually have no (nonstatic) members, they are in fact empty classes, so inheriting from them means that the Empty Base Class Optimization applies. So what the cons could be:

1. Inheritance normally implies an *is-a* relationship. OO-Purists therfore might say you should not use it for pure technical resons. But in C++ that pure technical inheritance is used often, so I would not bother.
2. If you have more than one base class, some compilers won't apply the EBCO any more, so the trait base class object that you inherit will occupy some space in your class objects, although it contains no data.

More material on inheritance, EBCO etc.:

- [Herb Sutter on Uses and Abuses of Inheritance](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill07.htm)
- [Boost.Operators documentation on base class chaining](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#chaining)

Comment: There are a lot of traits classes which aren't just a bunch of typedefs.  (I'm making extensive use of traits in my current work: I want to use template functions for a lot of things, but I'm interfacing to C, where each function has a distinct name.  So I use traits to wrap the C functions, and can do the rest with my templates.)

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, as the discussion to Jan's answer shows, the notion of a traits class is a bit fuzzy, but surely traits can also contain functions, I might have oversimplified that a bit.

Comment: @ArneMertz FWIW, the orginal publication outside of the C++ committee was http://www.cantrip.org/traits.html.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, sort of.  I would distinguish between the OO concept
of inheritance, and the C++ implementation technique of
derivation.  (This choice of vocabulary is personal.  The
distinction is not often made, but IMHO, it is important to
distinguish between the design concept, and the implementation
technique.)  In this case, I would say that you don't *inherit*
from a traits class, since there is no isA relationship.  On the
other hand, while derivation is usually used to implement
inheritance, it's not the only possible use.  It's perfectly
normal to derive from a traits class (e.g. in the way most
iterators will derive from `std::iterator`), as long as it is
clear that this derivation is *not* used to implement
inheritance, in the OO sense.  In particular, you don't want
people manipulating your iterator through pointers to
`std::iterator`.

It has been suggested (by none less than Herb Sutter) that
traits classes have protected destructors, to prevent any risk
of deletion through them.  I'm not totally convinced.  The very
semantics of a traits class are such that it won't normally even
occur to anyone to create a pointer to one.  (When was the last
time you saw an `std::iterator*` in any code?)  (On the other
hand, one may ask: why not?  The protected destructor does mean
that the traits class is not a POD, but I can't think of any
reasonable case where this matters.)

Any way, publicly inheriting from a traits class to obtain
a number of `typedef` is a standard C++ idiom.